# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/my-app/register] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Please help with the below configuration of a spring mvc application.
I'm trying to forward the request from the jsp to the controller but it is giving the warning related to http request mapping to the servlet.

**WEB.xml**

```
<web-app>
<display-name>my-app</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

```
**spring-servlet.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

<!-- telling container to take care of annotations stuff -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- declaring base package -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.Controller" />

<!-- adding view resolver to show jsp's on browser -->
<bean id="viewResolver"

 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="userDao" class="com.DaoImpl.UserDaoImpl" />
<bean id="userService" class="com.serviceImpl.UserServiceImpl" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE" />
    <property name="username" value="hr" />
    <property name="password" value="system" />
</bean>
```

**ERROR:**

```
  Apr 29, 2017 4:09:52 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
  INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
  Apr 29, 2017 4:09:53 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
  INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': startup date [Sat Apr 29 16:09:52 IST 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
  Apr 29, 2017 4:09:53 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
  INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': startup date [Sat Apr 29 16:09:52 IST 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
  Apr 29, 2017 4:09:53 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
  INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  Apr 29, 2017 4:09:53 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
  INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization completed in 118 ms
  Apr 29, 2017 4:09:53 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
  INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
   Apr 29, 2017 4:09:53 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
   INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
  Apr 29, 2017 4:09:53 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
   INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/26  config=null
  Apr 29, 2017 4:09:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
  INFO: Server startup in 1660 ms
  Apr 29, 2017 4:09:53 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound 
   noHandlerFound
  WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/my-app/register] in 
  DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

Kindly assist what is wrong with the above configuration.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your *web.xml* according to the correct mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Optimize it as you want. Or at the controller level you can handle it

```
@Controller
public class yourController {
    @RequestMapping("/register")
    public ModelAndView controllerMethod() {
            //...
    }
}
```

Of course the second approach is better. Ah and one more possibility; be sure that your controller is scanned if you think you've done the correct request mapping already at that level. Check whether your 
"context:component-scan base-package="..." /" configuration at your config xml or @ComponentScan("...") annotation at your config class is pointing to the right packages.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In your spring-servlet.xml try to add the annotation `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to allow dispatching requests to Controllers.

This annotation add support for : @RequestMapping, @Controller, although support for those is the default behaviour.